# Replace Street Names (Strings) with Letters in alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So i have a dataset with a few columns. However, one column is made out of locations, in this case street names. I would like to rename those to just one letter. So for example:

| Location | Location new |
| --- | --- |
| Beukenlaan | A |
| Deventerlaan | B |
| Crixstraat | C |
| Deventerlaan | B |

I have to do this for multiple datasheets so the function below would take a lot of time to adjust manually.

```
df.replace('Eindhoven Genovevalaan', 'A', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Any ideas how to do this automatically?

Comment: you should give a bit more details about the logic, and potential limitations of the data (duplicated locations, etc.) and what should happen in this case

Comment: My datafile indeed has multiple duplicate location names, could that result in it not working?

Comment: it depends what you want to do in this case

Comment: I want to replace all 'Beukenlaan' with A

Comment: Does the order matter? or any order is fine?

Comment: Any order is fine!

Comment: OK, then the logic is different, check my update

Comment: Works like a charm thanks! Maybe, is it possible if for example i would want another static label in front of the Letters, so that it would become Dust_A, Dust_B, Dust_C. What is the easiest way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) and `string.ascii_uppercase`:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import numpy as np

d = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))

df['Location new'] = pd.Series(df['Location'].factorize()[0]).map(d)
```

*NB. there are only 26 values in `ascii_uppercase` (`'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`) so you need to specify what should happen if you have more than 26 rows.*

output:

```
       Location Location new
0    Beukenlaan            A
1  Deventerlaan            B
2    Crixstraat            C
3  Deventerlaan            B
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortenately, the code doesn't output the Letters in the column. It does make them blank tho. I editted my first post to show the full code

Comment: @Nindooo then you're doing something incorrectly ;) Can you provide a minimal reproducible example (i.e. not relying on an external file)